# How to read a lens spot diagram?

Tags: optics

I would like to get an explanation on how to understand such a lens spot diagram: [image: Spot diagram in Zemax]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The size of the spot is the size an image of a point source will be on you detector.

In other words, the spot diagram gives indication of the image of a point object.  In the absence of aberrations, a point object will converge to a perfect image point.

Comment: Thanks. Meaning that for the same object point, I have a different size of spot for each pixel of my sensor? Here IMA: 0.000MM refers to the center of the sensor? And IMA: 5.500MM refers to a point located at 5.5000MM of the center?

Comment: Not exactly a point, by 5.5mm must be the size of a point source you would be able to see ont he screen going by the above definition :) @Raphael

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what means IMA: 5.5MM/0.0MM/3.0MM..

Comment: IMA describes the location of the centroid on the imaging surface

Comment: This [Biphotonics](http://wiki.mcmaster.ca/Biophotonics/_media/public:publications:fangq_wangrcc_dual-view_jbo_2011.pdf?id=people%3Afangq&cache=cache) article should help you . Dont wrorry by the bophotonics name, go to fig 6 and related discussion, you will be at bay :) @Raphael

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2187/discussion-between-raphael-and-jack)

Comment: chat doesnt work with the proxy of internet i use, so i am afraid we will have to continue our discussion here itself

Comment: It looks to me like those are the on-axis spots at different positions OF the surface - ie at different focus?

Comment: I'm still don't understand what are those differents forms. The spot size @ IMA: 5.500MM looks better and more concentrate than @ IMA: 0.00MM.

Comment: I am from non physics background and tried to make you understand with whatever limited knowledge i had